# flink1.17.1, start-cluster.sh, it show error in log. akka.tcp://flink@flink01:34428

Tags: apache-flink

After start start-cluster.sh in flink 1.17.1, it get some error in log.
Association with remote system [akka.tcp://flink@flink01:43676] has failed, address is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Association failed with [akka.tcp://flink@flink01:43676]] Caused by: [java.net.ConnectException: 拒绝连接: flink01/192.168.100.148:43676]

Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://flink@flink01:34428],
it use flink user, we expect it should use root user, why it is flink user?

how can I fix it. it should be kka.tcp://root@flink01:34428